# Old computer does not power on

Tags: motherboard, power

I have an old computer I'd like to back to life for testing purposes. Since a few months ago it does not power on. I did change nothing. One day I tried to power it on, and it didn't work. I disassembled and assembled back again all their components, devices and cables, to make sure there wasn't a connection problem.

Although I'm not sure, I think its problem is the tower power button that does not work, but I don't know how to test it. I know motherboard gets power because its Onboard LED is ON, but when I push the tower power button is does nothing.

It is a very old ASUS A7V333-X motherboard. According to its manual, this is its power connector:

[image: Power Connector]

Is it a way to simulate push power button? I've been thinking to connect "Power Switch" pins using any kind of switch or using a jumper or just using a screwdriver to connect them, but I'm afraid I'd be short-circuit or something worse.

I guess pins involved would be:

[image: Power Switch pins]

What do you think? It will work or it will crash? Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do exactly as your instinct tells you and bridge the PWR pin to its' ground.

Does a power button magically makes a complex signal for the computer to understand?

No! It just bridges the two pins on the motherboard responsible for telling the MOBO when to boot.

> First, make sure that you've got your motherboard isolated from anything conductive. In the past I've measured the motherboard and put standoffs on a sheet of cardboard. Then just connect everything as usual.
>
> Now you need some way to trigger the computer to start up. The easiest way to do this is to find the pins that the power switch from your front panel connects to (should be printed on the motherboard and/or listed in the manual) and then short the two pins with a screwdriver or jumper (this isn't very good for the motherboard). The best way would be to attach a 2-pin connector to a momentary-on switch and then connect that to the motherboard header (just like how it's done inside a case). After you hear the fan start up, make sure that you stop or take away whatever is shorting the pins (or else the system will restart after ten seconds or so).
>
> #### Taken from [Tom's Hardware Forum](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/294441-31-start-computer-putting-case)

I DO NOT recommend using a screwdriver, instead use a header shunt. You can buy them on Amazon or some other merchant. After some quick googling, I found a pretty cheap one [here](https://www.peconnectors.com/shunts-jumpers/hws1715/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA1NbhBRCBARIsAKOTmUuAPpQN-SsAzlpvx55Tms74B9S9RA9XFC0Ic-wkulMGTM273Z5tpqYaAgtDEALw_wcB). I'm sure you probably have one lying around if you're into tower computers.

If you'd like to avoid spending money, even a paper clip would work...

Either way, be gentle and release after hearing the fans start to spin.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Just a couple of quick questions. 1- Why is it ok to use a paper clip, but not a screwdriver to bridge the two pins? At least using a screwdriver the handle has an isolation layer to avoid any electric discharge. 2- You say "_release after hearing the fans start to spin_", but if I use a jumper (I guess it's the same as a header shunt), to connect the two pins, those won't be disconnected after computer powers on. What don't I understand?

Comment: You put the header shunt/jumper on and pull it off after fans start up. Same with a paper clip or any metal you use to short the pins. I recommend against a screwdriver because if you aren't careful you can bend the pins, and a paperclip is unlikely to cause damage to the board if you slip off of the pins you're trying to short. A screwdriver could cause anything from a scratch to a puncture of the board. I don't think you understand the point here. There is very little electricity going through that jumper / paperclip. It's very low voltage and will not arc.